# Python Code to only print words from a list that start with an A

Tags: python

I have to print words from an array that only start with A.

```
w = ["Algorithm", "Logic", "Filter", "Software", "Network", "Parameters", "Analyze", "Algorithm", "Functionality", "Viruses"]
```

for i in range (len(w)):

```
if(w == "A"):
    print(w[i])
```

'# print (w[i].upper())'

The output should be:

Algorithm

Analyze

Algorithm

I am confused on how you would get a word that starts with an A. This is what I have so far. Any suggestions? I am not allowed to use any other methods like startswith and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use list comprehension if you wanted to store this in a list:

```
result = [word for word in w if word[0] == "A"]
```

Or, just plain looping (if you want to just print the words out):

```
for word in w:
    if word[0] == "A":
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `startswith` method of strings like this:

```py
w = ["Algorithm", "Logic", "Filter", "Software", "Network", "Parameters", "Analyze", "Algorithm", "Functionality", "Viruses"]

for word in w:
    if word.startswith('A'):
        print(word)

>>> Algorithm
>>> Analyze
>>> Algorithm
```

EDIT: Since you can't use `startswith`, access the first position of the word and compare it:

```py
for word in w:
    if word[0] == 'A':
        print(word)
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use any other methods like that

Comment: "I am not allowed to use any other methods like startswith and etc." Maybe instead, use `[0]` (to get the first character of the string)